# Magento custom filter on listing page gives incorrect product count

Tags: php, mysql, magento, filter, product

I am displaying listing page with products. And I applied custom filter to filter out the products.

Code in `list.phtml`:

```
$postCodeQueryStr = $this->getRequest()->getParam('post_code');

$_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter(
                array(
                    array('attribute'=>'town', 'like' => ''.$postCodeQueryStr.'%'),
                    array('attribute'=>'post_code', 'like' => ''.$postCodeQueryStr.'%')
                )
        )

        ->clear()->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC');
```

To show count or products I used:

`echo $_productCollection->getSize()`

Here initially through `$this->getLoadedProductCollection()`, I get All products and then I am filter it using `addAttributeToFilter()`. It shows limited products actually. By this I mean it filters out to show limited products related to criteria.

[image]

But instead of showing filtered count, it shows whole count of products, it doesn't show count after filtering by criteria.

I am getting limited products in list, but count of them is old (before filter).

Comment: What is clear()'s effect ? Try removing it.

Comment: I tried removing it already, still doesn't work

Comment: Do you know how to extract the sql query from the collection ? Check the result set manually.

Comment: Its getting printed well and works well, just the issue is it doesnt show count properly. And we cant use regular sql query as it use OOP to set lots of properties etc. Have you worked with listing in magento with filtering?

Comment: Evaluate this: `echo $_productCollection->getSelect()->__toString();` (note there are two `_`), copy and paste the query to mysql (preferably with `https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/`), and check if the result set count is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are filtering on the template level , and the count is rendered in the toolbar before that.
so you have to put your filter in the

```
function getLoadedProductCollection()
```

which further uses the function

```
public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
        ->addCategoryFilter($this);
    return $collection;
}
```

located at 
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php

you can add your filter here .

i will suggest you to not to edit this core file and switch it to your local folder .

let me know if there is any doubt.

thanks hope it will do your work.

Comment: please check the full function below for your needs.Just use this function and you will be all done.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the function like below according to your needs Just replace this function as below and you will all done. thanks

```
    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $postCodeQueryStr = $_POST['post_code'];
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
            ->addCategoryFilter($this);
        if($postCodeQueryStr!=''){
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
                array(
                    array('attribute'=>'town', 'like' => ''.$postCodeQueryStr.'%'),
                    array('attribute'=>'post_code', 'like' => ''.$postCodeQueryStr.'%')
                )
        )
        ->clear()->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC');
            }
        return $collection;
    }
```

Comment: You could modify your above answer and you could add another approach there itself. No need to have 2 different answers.

Comment: `it doesnt work ` means it doesnt sort/filter, it simply returns ALL products

Comment: have you check is it comming in condition           if($postCodeQueryStr!=''){    by printing something in this

Comment: you have to chnage $_GET['post_code'];  to $_POST['post_code'];in above code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92010/discussion-between-rohit-goel-and-pratik-c-joshi).